# Android Exception: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am pretty new to Android.I am working on a small android application for learning new concepts.

I am working on `fragments`. I got stuck while making an HTTP request.I am using `HttpUrlConnection` library for accomplishing my task.

I have created the following code so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

MainActivityFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    String forecastJsonStr = null;
    int resCode = -1;

    try {

        URL url= new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&APPID=XXX");

        urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        resCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        Log.d("responce", forecastJsonStr);
    }

    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

//You can ignore the lower portion of the code. I have just created an arraylist of weather and am showing on the android app

    String[] data={"Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"};

    List<String> weekForcast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForcast);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forcast);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Whenever i try to run the code, i get the following error:

```
> Process: com.example.android.udacityclass, PID: 20766 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.android.udacityclass/com.example.android.udacityclass.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
> inflating class fragment 02-05 16:54:20.695
> 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) 02-05 16:54:20.695
> 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 02-05 16:54:20.695
> 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary
> XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment 02-05 16:54:20.695
> 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> com.example.android.udacityclass.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)  02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> 02-05 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)  02-05
> 16:54:20.695 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method)  02-05 16:54:20.695
> 20766-20766/com.example.android.udacityclass E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this error. Also, can someone help me in finding references of debugging errors in android. Thanks a lot

Comment: share your layout too

Comment: @playmaker420 The link of the layout is attached : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08OnKHLvyhmMEhocmYwYV9aV2c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are making your request on the main Thread, use Asynctask<> to make request in the background thread. Look at this link for how to use, make your http request in the doInbackground method.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

for further details on android background processes checkout this link 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
Hope this help.